# Distributive law between monads in Haskell

Tags: functional-programming, ct.category-theory, haskell, monad

[A distributive law between monads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_law_between_monads) must satisfy laws that are usually given in terms of the units $\eta$ and multiplications $\mu$ of the two monads. Among the four laws there are:

- $\mu^S T \circ S l \circ l S = l \circ T \mu^S$, and
- $S \mu^T \circ l T \circ T l = l \circ \mu^T S$

I would like to state those laws in Haskell in terms of `fmap`, `return` and `(>>=)`. By replacing $\mu$ in the above equation I respectively get:

- `fmap l (l n) >>= id  ==  l (fmap (\m  -> m >>= id) n)`, and
- `fmap (\m -> m >>= id) (l (fmap l n))  ==  l (n >>= id)`

But those equations in this form are not very useful for making proofs by rewriting because such patterns never arise directly in practice and thus I cannot use them for rewriting.

Is there a nicer, smarter and equivalent way to define a distributive law for monads in Haskell terms of `fmap`, `return` and `(>>=)`? I searched the literature on Haskell but the closer I found were [monad transformers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_transformer) which seem to involve special cases of distributive law where one of the monad is fixed. However I am interested in the general case.

Comment: Two arbitrary monads do not satisfy the distributive law in general.  What do you mean by the general case in the last sentence?

Comment: Thank you @TsuyoshiIto for trying to help but I am not so stupid (^O^)  The "general case" in the last sentence is with respect to the previous sentence.

Comment: I know that it is with respect to the previous sentence, and that is why I am confused.  Because distributive law needs two monads (and function l), fixing one monad is not even a special case of it.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Take for example `MaybeT m a` that is equal to `m (Maybe a)`: there is a distributive law where the first monad $T$ is the variable `m` while the second monad $U$ is fixed to `Maybe`. Does it clarify?

Comment: I think that you meant S is an arbitrary monad and T is `Maybe`.  Sure, I can believe that this particular choice satisfies the distributive law with l = `maybe (return Nothing) (fmap Just)`, but what is the more “general case” than this you are interested in?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Bob asks for a Haskell definition of (the type of) distributive law where both monads are parameters; not for a theorem proving this type for two arbitrary monads.